# How to have maximum one property present for a Typescript interface

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, interface

Having the following interface for a React component:

```
export interface MyInterface  {
  name: string;
  isEasy?: boolean;
  isMedium?: boolean;
  isHard?: boolean;
}
```

It must accept maximum one property of the last three (isEasy, isMedium or isHard)

For example

```
<MyComponent name='John' /> // correct
<MyComponent name='John' isEasy /> // correct
<MyComponent name='John' isEasy isHard /> // incorrect
```

How can it be done?

Tried to union them like this without success:

```
interface MyInterface {
  name: string;
}

interface MyInterfaceEasy extends MyInterface {
  isEasy: true;
  isMedium?: never;
  isHard?: never;
}

interface MyInterfaceMedium extends MyInterface {
  isEasy: never;
  isMedium?: true;
  isHard?: never;
}

interface MyInterfaceHard extends MyInterface {
  isEasy: never;
  isMedium?: never;
  isHard?: true;
}

export type ExportedInterface =
  | MyInterfaceEasy
  | MyInterfaceMedium
  | MyInterfaceHard;
```

When testing it with: `<MyComponent name='John' isEasy />`

Error:

```
Types of property 'isEasy' are incompatible.
Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'undefined'
```

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing that is to always have one of the difficulties be `true` and the rest `?: false`. That way you can omit all props or all but one. Setting two difficulties will set both to `true` and therefore they won't be assignable to `ExportedInterface` and Typescript will error.

You can see an example of this here or in the [Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=27&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#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):

```
interface MyInterface {
  name: string;
}

interface MyInterfaceEasy extends MyInterface {
  isEasy?: true;
  isMedium?: false;
  isHard?: false;
}

interface MyInterfaceMedium extends MyInterface {
  isEasy?: false;
  isMedium?: true;
  isHard?: false;
}

interface MyInterfaceHard extends MyInterface {
  isEasy?: false;
  isMedium?: false;
  isHard?: true;
}

export type ExportedInterface =
  | MyInterfaceEasy
  | MyInterfaceMedium
  | MyInterfaceHard;

declare const Component: FC<ExportedInterface>;

// OK
<Component name='none' />;
<Component name='easy' isEasy />;
<Component name='medium' isMedium />;
<Component name='hard' isHard />;
// Not OK
<Component name='mix' isEasy isHard />;
```

You might also consider taking a different approach where you have one prop that is `difficulty?: 'easy' | 'medium' | 'hard'`. That would only allow one difficulty.

You can see that approach here or in the [Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=7&ssc=1&pln=9&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8CS5rycgbwChlkQ4BbCALmQGcwpQBzAbhOQBNgYZgEArgBsw6APy0A5BDh10k5AB9kkqtwEUFyyQAs4UTpPYBfIkWAUADgHsoYZACUZCMABpCAMQDCx5DCjWFCpQzmBGZpwQCEL6KAjWIAzIXoE2IBDgtN4APBjYkLCIEAB87ETZKVYJGfbkVAC8kiDVCgD0peWVaTVklBCNMnIK3Lz8wqIDsvLI7ewVqdXgvQ2qEOqaXDx8giLojWrAGm0d81XpS3X9uvqGm6M7E9cGx+ytrcgActbIAO5w6MgwN8IAA3DLIPRg5AUcbASxCFAjbawiB0IA):

```
interface MyInterface {
  name: string;
  difficulty?: 'easy' | 'medium' | 'hard';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can change your code to:

```js
interface MyBaseInterface {
  name: string;
}

interface MyInterfaceEasy extends MyBaseInterface {
  isEasy?: boolean;
}

interface MyInterfaceMedium extends MyBaseInterface {
  isMedium?: boolean;
}

interface MyInterfaceHard extends MyBaseInterface {
  isHard?: boolean;
}

export type ExportedInterface =
  | MyInterfaceEasy
  | MyInterfaceMedium
  | MyInterfaceHard;
```

and it should works.